# How to use numpy nper?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a math issue ,which I want to do is than:

p: present value

f: future value

r: rate

n: year

and I have p/f/r value , then want to calcuate n.
I think , the math equation is

```
p * r^n >= f
```

so I use numpy to do that , I think the usage is

```
np.nper(r,0,p,f)
```

but I got nan ... is any parameter I set are wrong ?

Then , has any numpy usage can calcuate below equation to get n :

```
pr + pr^2 + pr^3 + ... + pr^n >= another one number
```

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't the numpy notes help? the number of periods is calculated using: `fv + pv*(1+rate)**nper + pmt*(1+rate*when)/rate*((1+rate)**nper-1) = 0`. I think you shouldn't pass the future value to `nper`

Comment: OMG, I think I am quite unconscious. :( , it's easy way to use np.log to solve the equation... n  =  np.log(f/p) / np.log(r)